# What's the 'Ruby way' to iterate over two arrays at once

Tags: ruby, arrays, iterator

More of a syntax curiosity than a problem to solve...

I have two arrays of equal length, and want to iterate over them both at once - for example, to output both their values at a certain index.

```
@budget = [ 100, 150, 25, 105 ]
@actual = [ 120, 100, 50, 100 ]
```

I know that I can use `each_index` and index into the arrays like so:

```
@budget.each_index do |i|
  puts @budget[i]
  puts @actual[i]
end
```

Is there a *Ruby way* to do this better? Something *like* this?

```
# Obviously doesn't achieve what I want it to - but is there something like this?
[@budget, @actual].each do |budget, actual|
  puts budget
  puts actual
end
```

Comment: are both the arrays of equal sizes?

Comment: Yep - both known to be of the same length

Answer (score 289, accepted):

```
>> @budget = [ 100, 150, 25, 105 ]
=> [100, 150, 25, 105]
>> @actual = [ 120, 100, 50, 100 ]
=> [120, 100, 50, 100]

>> @budget.zip @actual
=> [[100, 120], [150, 100], [25, 50], [105, 100]]

>> @budget.zip(@actual).each do |budget, actual|
?>   puts budget
>>   puts actual
>> end
100
120
150
100
25
50
105
100
=> [[100, 120], [150, 100], [25, 50], [105, 100]]
```

Comment: '.each' can unfold array elements? I wonder how much more of Ruby I don't know :/

Comment: If you're going to use an expression like that, it's always best to use parentheses for method calls, just in case.  @budget.zip(@actual).each

Comment: @AboutRuby: In this case, it's needed! Fixed.

Comment: @AboutRuby, Marc-André, ah yes it's needed for 1.8, not for 1.9 though. Better to have the answer work for both though, I agree

Comment: when i see ruby lines like this, i throw my hands in the air and wal round the room like a champ!

Comment: I realize your example mirrors the question, but I think you should change your example so that one of them is numbers, the other letters.  That would make it far clearer what's going on in the zipped array what is going where.

Comment: Does this scale? If I have 2 10000 item arrays does this require making a 20,000 item array? The docs suggest this.

Comment: @AboutRuby What about this makes you need paranthesess? I thought if there was only level of nested arguments, you don't really need parentheses.

Comment: is there a way to also add an index to the zip?

Comment: @TomAndersen it is definitely inefficient. Using @Donato's solution or just `each_with_index` will be a lot more memory and CPU efficient.

Comment: @TomAndersen Use `arr1.lazy.zip(arr2)` if you want to be memory-friendly.

Answer (score 21):

Use the [`Array.zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) method and pass it a block to iterate over the corresponding elements sequentially.

Answer (score 21):

There is another way to iterate over two arrays at once using enumerators:

```
2.1.2 :003 > enum = [1,2,4].each
 => #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 4]:each> 
2.1.2 :004 > enum2 = [5,6,7].each
 => #<Enumerator: [5, 6, 7]:each> 
2.1.2 :005 > loop do
2.1.2 :006 >     a1,a2=enum.next,enum2.next
2.1.2 :007?>   puts "array 1 #{a1} array 2 #{a2}"
2.1.2 :008?>   end
array 1 1 array 2 5
array 1 2 array 2 6
array 1 4 array 2 7
```

Enumerators are more powerful than the examples used above, because they allow infinite series, parallel iteration, among other techniques.

Comment: Is there a way to get the index inside the `loop` shown above?

Comment: @Biju, you can write `e1 = [1,2,4].each_with_index` and `e2 = [5,6,7].each_with_index`. Then `e1.next #=> [1, 0]; e1.next #=> [2, 1]; e1.next #=> [4, 2]; e1.next #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end (exception)`. Similar for `e2`.

Answer (score 17):

Related to the original question, for iterating over arrays of *unequal* length where you want the values to cycle around you can use

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6].zip([7,8,9].cycle)
```

and Ruby will give you

```
[[1, 7], [2, 8], [3, 9], [4, 7], [5, 8], [6, 9]]
```

This saves you from the `nil` values that you'll get from just using zip

Answer (score 16):

In addition to `a.zip(b).each{|x,y| }` as others have said, you can also say `[a,b].transpose.each{|x,y| }`, which strikes me as a tiny bit more symmetrical. Probably not as fast, though, since you're creating the extra `[a,b]` array.

Comment: +1 One of the nice things about `transpose` is it raises an exception if the two arrays aren't the same length.

Answer (score 7):

Simply zipping the two arrays together works well if you are dealing with arrays. But what if you are dealing with never-ending enumerators, such as something like these:

```
enum1 = (1..5).cycle
enum2 = (10..12).cycle
```

`enum1.zip(enum2)` fails because `zip` tries to evaluate all the elements and combine them. Instead, do this:

```
enum1.lazy.zip(enum2)
```

That one `lazy` saves you by making the resulting enumerator lazy-evaluate.

Comment: This is also useful if you want to are using arrays but want to keep the memory footprint low.

Answer (score 3):

How about compromising, and using #each_with_index?

```
include Enumerable 

@budget = [ 100, 150, 25, 105 ]
@actual = [ 120, 100, 50, 100 ]

@budget.each_with_index { |val, i| puts val; puts @actual[i] }
```