# Ruby code to iterate through two array simulataneoulsy

Tags: ruby

How can I iterate two array in ruby simultaneously , I don't want to use for loop. 
for e.g this are my array=

```
array 1=["a","b","c","d"]
array 2=[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `for` anyways.  You almost always want `each`.

Comment: @squiguy following the herd doesn't necessarily mean you're doing the right thing ;) check out the docs: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Comment: @alfasin, your comment makes little sense. It sounds like you're trying to use Benchmark as justification to use `for`. There are good reasons `for` is not the preferred path for array traversal so please enlighten us.

Comment: @theTinMan unless you back up your claim with valid arguments (and I already provided my argument) - saying that what I write "makes little sense" is just insulting (I didn't take any offence though ;) ). I know it's not "common" for Ruby programmers to use `for` loops, but I don't see any good reason for that. I totally agree with this guy: http://paulphilippov.com/articles/enumerable-each-vs-for-loops-in-ruby

Comment: `for`, along with using `while` increases the likelihood of indexing errors when traversing arrays. Languages like Perl, which allows `foreach` to traverse the array, and Ruby, using `each` circumvent the index problems by returning each element sequentially. There is no index and no worry of missing an element or trying to get too many. This is not following the herd, is defensive programming.

Comment: @alfasin Have you run this benchmark with Ruby 2.0 ? Differences are very small, but the `for` version is the slowest.

Comment: `for`, when used to iterate over an array, also exposes what should be an temporary variable to hold the element. That new temporary variable clutters the namespace, unlike using a block with `each`, which creates a new scope, isolating its temporary variable, which disappears when the block exits. Also, `for` is built using `each` so you'd have added some additional complexity for syntactic sugar that slows your code. Exposing trash variables and slowing execution seem like good reasons to avoid it.

Comment: steenslag - okay, so `for` has no advantage since Ruby 2.0 but it doesn't necessarily mean it has meaningful disadvantages as well. @theTinMan personally, I find these two arguments (which actually say the same thing - help preventing confusion) to be weak - as so many other languages use it - and I don't think that Ruby programmers are "dumber"... I feel that Ruby programmers prefer using `each` in order to feel "superior" comparing to other "old" languages like c++ and Java. And when "ego" sets the mind-set, not much good can come out of it. Don't hate `for` - he's one of the good guys! ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the 'Ruby way' to iterate over two arrays at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580049/whats-the-ruby-way-to-iterate-over-two-arrays-at-once)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use zip function for example like this :

```
array1.zip(array2).each do |array1_var, array2_var|
 ## whatever you want to do with array_1var and array_2 var 
 end
```

Comment: I think it is because the guy who asked question does not want to use for loop may be because of some of usage reason like in some cases where we have array of hashes it  for loop become very trivial for e.g array like this :[{"name"=>"Default", "stocks"=>[{"name"=>"Ajanta Pharma Ltd.", "id"=>"id1", "qty"=>"10"}]}, {"name"=>"low margin", "stocks"=>[{"name"=>"Atul Auto Ltd.", "id"=>"id5", "qty"=>"12"}, {"name"=>"new", "stocks"=>[{"name"=>"Hindustan Zinc Ltd.", "id"=>"id6", "qty"=>"13"}]}]

Comment: would their be a way to also add an index to this? in order to keep track of the loop count.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) (no need to use `each` because `zip` accept optional block):

```
array1 = ["a","b","c","d"]
array2 = [1,2,3,4]

array1.zip(array2) do |a, b|
  p [a,b]
end
```

Or, [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose):

```
[array1, array2].transpose.each do |a, b|
  p [a,b]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `zip` them together and then iterate through the pairs using `each`.

```
array1.zip(array2).each do |pair|
  p pair
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if both arrays are of the same size, you can do:

```
array1=["a","b","c","d"]
array2=[1,2,3,4]

for i in 0..arr1.length do
 //here you do what you want with array1[i] and array2[i]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays are the same size, you can use `each_with_index` to iterate through them, using the index for the second array:

```
array1.each_with_index do |item1, index|
  item2 = array2[index]
  # do something with item1, item2
end
```

Like so:

```
irb(main):007:0> array1.each_with_index do |item1, index|
irb(main):008:1*   item2 = array2[index]
irb(main):009:1>   puts item1, item2
irb(main):010:1> end
a
1
b
2
c
3
d
4
```

Answer (score 0):

When both of the array are of having same size,you could do as below :

```
array1=["a","b","c","d"]
array2=[1,2,3,4]

array2.each_index{|i| p "#{array2[i]},#{array1[i]} at location #{i}"}

# >> "1,a at location 0"
# >> "2,b at location 1"
# >> "3,c at location 2"
# >> "4,d at location 3"
```

And if there is a chance that one array is larger than other array,then `larger_array#each_index` has to be called.