# Merging Array objects into hash with an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of rooms: `rooms_array = [room1...roomn]` and each room is a hash with respective details. Each room hash has an offers hash. 
`room1 = {...., offers=> {...},...}`
Now I have another array of offers hashes.
`avg_array = [[{offer1},{offer2}],[{offer4},{offer3}],....]`
Length of both the hashes is same, so first array of avg_array is for room1, second for room2 and so on...
My problem is how do I add each array of avg_array into corresponding offers hash of rooms_array.

My attempt:

```
_rooms.values.map do |room|
  if room[:offers].count > 1
    i=0
    room[:offers] = rooms_hash[i]
    i = i + 1
  end
end
```

Comment: `{offer1}` is not a valid Ruby object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you might be able to do something using `Array.zip`

```
rooms.zip(avg_array).map do |room,avg|
  room[:offers] = avg
  room
end
```

If you want to append to an existing array:

```
rooms.zip(avg_array).map do |room,avg|
  room[:offers] ||= []
  room[:offers].concat avg
  room
end
```

see:
[What's the 'Ruby way' to iterate over two arrays at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580049/whats-the-ruby-way-to-iterate-over-two-arrays-at-once)

Comment: Is it possible to first check for id in both and then insert. Lets say both has an id for this purpose.

Comment: Yeah - within that loop you can examine both the room and avg object and do whatever with them.  The zip means they will always be in step though, so you'll only see room[5] with avg[5]... you can't directly access avg[x+1] or avg[x-1] (you don't know what x is!)   Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah it does. I used a select statement to check for the item.