# Array operations on two different arrays in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-loops

I have two arrays:

1. names = [ "John", "Jason", "Lisa" ]
2. things = [ "Chocolate", "Sugar", "Candy" ]

The result I want is:

John- chocolate,

Jason - Sugar

Lisa - Candy

What I am doing is :

```
names.each do |name|
  puts "#{name} likes: "

  things.each do |item|
    puts "  #{item}"
  end
end
```

which gives me :

John likes: 
  Chocolate 
  Sugar 
  Candy

Jason likes: 
  Chocolate 
  Sugar 
  Candy

Lisa likes: 
  Chocolate 
  Sugar 
  Candy

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580049/whats-the-ruby-way-to-iterate-over-two-arrays-at-once) is what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks, @joacho, this also solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [each_with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_index) to use the index of `names` array to find the element from `things` array.

```
names = [ "John", "Jason", "Lisa" ]
things = [ "Chocolate", "Sugar", "Candy" ]

names.each_with_index do |value, index|
  puts "#{value} likes: #{things[index]}"
end
```